# Why do NRF24L01 modules only communicate in 1 direction

Tags: communication, arduino-pro-mini, nrf24l01+

I have 2 NRF24L01 +pa +lna modules connected to 2 arduino mini pros. One of the modules is on a joystick and the other one is on a airplane. Everything worked perfectly until last week when they stopped communicating. So I wrote a simple receiver and transceiver code to see if they worked. The result is that if the module on the plane is the transceiver and the joystick is the receiver everything works fine. If they have the opposite roles then I only get empty messages onto the serial monitor way more often than the transceiver sends a message.

Receiver code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8);

const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  while (!Serial);
    Serial.begin(9600);
  
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.startListening();

}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available())
  {
    char text[32] = {0};
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
  }

}
```

Transceiver code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7,8);

const byte address[6] = "00001";


void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.stopListening();

}

void loop() {

  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  delay (1000);
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: There are a lot of Chinese clones of the nRF24L01+ chips around, and some work better than others.

Comment: switch the modules around

Answer (score 1):

In receiving code....try only defining variable.
char text[32];

You change the datarate , palevel and channel in nrf24l01.
See datasheet for more info.
Or visit https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-wireless-communication-nrf24l01-tutorial/

You may have power issue because pro mini might not deliver sufficient....to neglect use a 10uf Cap in nrf.